# Releasing an instance of view controller

Tags: xcode, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am having trouble releasing myCameraViewController in Xcode. I have set up a delegate and will send message from cameraViewController to my UploadView. In my UploadView, there is a button which will create an instance of cameraViewController and call its useCamera method. The use Camera method will let the user to take a photo and once the user finishes taking a photo, the delegate will return the photo to the UploadView.

```
- (void)camButtonClick:(id)sender{
    cameraViewController *myCameraViewController = [[cameraViewController alloc] init];
    myCameraViewController.delegate = self;
    [myCameraViewController useCamera];
    //[myCameraViewController release]; 
}
```

My problem is I am not sure where should I release myCameraView? if I release it within the camButtonClick block, it will cause a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I guess it is because the release is too early as we need to wait for the delegate to return before releasing the myCameraViewController.

Comment: Sorry I am new to xcode. What is ARC?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting